# CSS writing animation alternate infinite cuts last letter off

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I want to create a writing animation which is infinite and alternate. Everything works fine but for some reason the last letter does always get cut off.

I hope somebody can explain why it gets cut off and how to fix this.

My code:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.first {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.first::before,
.first::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.5rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.first::before {
  background-color: white;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(7) alternate infinite;
}

.first::after {
  width: .125rem;
  background-color: black;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(7) alternate infinite, blink 500ms steps(7) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="first">student</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generic method from my article:  https://dev.to/afif/a-scalable-css-only-typewriter-effect-2opn

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.first {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.type {
  font-size:50px;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.type span {
  height:1.2em;
  width:0%;
  word-break:break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation:
    c 0.2s infinite steps(1),  
    t 3s linear infinite alternate;
}
.type span:before {
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
}

@keyframes t{
  90%,100% {width:100%}
}

@keyframes c{
  0%,100%{box-shadow:2px 0 0 #0000}
  50%    {box-shadow:2px 0 0 #000 }
}
```

```html
<li class="first type"><span>student</span></li>
```

Using your method, update the code like below. You have to consider 8 steps and add `1ch` to the final `left` value

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.first {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.first::before,
.first::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.first::before {
  background-color: white;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(8) alternate infinite;
}

.first::after {
  width: .125rem;
  background-color: black;
  animation: 
   typewriter 1.5s steps(8) alternate infinite,
   blink 500ms steps(8) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  to {
    left: calc(100% + 1ch);
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="first">student</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your `left` value and increase your `step` count.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.first {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.first::before,
.first::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.5rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.first::before {
  background-color: white;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(8) alternate infinite;
}

.first::after {
  width: .125rem;
  background-color: black;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(8) alternate infinite, blink 500ms steps(8) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  to {
    left: 110%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="first">student</li>
```

Longer words:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 3em 0;
}

.first {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.first::before,
.first::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.5rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.first::before {
  background-color: white;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(8) alternate infinite;
}

.first::after {
  width: .125rem;
  background-color: black;
  animation: typewriter 1.5s steps(8) alternate infinite, blink 500ms steps(8) infinite;
}

.second::before {
  background-color: white;
  animation: typewriter 2.5s steps(16) alternate infinite;
}

.second::after {
  width: .125rem;
  background-color: black;
  animation: typewriter 2.5s steps(16) alternate infinite, blink 500ms steps(16) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  to {
    left: 110%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="first">student</li>
<li class="first second">studentstudent</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By increasing the left value, the letters get cut every step.

Comment: @samuelhertrich See edits - it doesn't get cut if you increase your step count also.

Comment: It works for this particular word but I have more words and unfortunately it does not work with them. I don't want to create a keyframe for every single word.

Comment: @samuelhertrich You can see snippet #2 for a demonstration for longer words.